# Is D-Wave advantage a noisier hardware compared to the older D-Wave 2000?

Tags: noise, d-wave

Is D-Wave Advantage noisier hardware compared to the older D-Wave 2000? There is any [measure of the noise](https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/c_qpu_errors.html) within the [vendor's whitepapers](https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/doc_physical_properties.html), the quantum annealer analogue of e.g. decoherence time, fidelity in gate-based quantum hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Because of higher qubit counts and greater connectivity, the Advantage QPU can hold
inputs that are typically between 2 and 4 times larger than those that fit on the 2000Q QPU. Chain lengths on Advantage QPUs are generally half as long as those on the 2000Q. For a problem of Random Cliques The Advantage system significantly outperforms the 2000Q system. In this test the win percentage for the Advantage QPU was 45.83 percent, over six times higher than the win percentage of 6.67 percent for the 2000Q QPU.
Overall the Advantage system performs better than the 2000Q , but on the noise front, the 2000Q is still considered as the low noise dwave's qc.

You can find the detailed report between the comparison [here](https://www.dwavesys.com/media/s3qbjp3s/14-1049a-a_the_d-wave_advantage_system_an_overview.pdf)